# Why is this trigger to prevent event deletion not executing correctly?

Tags: trigger, profile, event, delete

I have written this trigger which is supposed to prevent a user (unless they are a system administrator, marketing director or telesales) deleting an event of type 'Telemarketing Appointment'. But when I try to delete an event of this type while logged in as a system administrator, it gives the error it should only give to a user who is not named above.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger PreventEventDeletion on Event (before delete)
{
    String ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
    List<Profile> profiles=[SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE name='System Administrator' OR name='Marketing Director' OR name='Telesales'];

    for (Event event : Trigger.old)
    {
        if (event.Type == 'Telemarketing Appointment')
        {
            if(( UserInfo.getProfileId()!=profiles[0].id) || ( UserInfo.getProfileId()!=profiles[1].id) || ( UserInfo.getProfileId()!=profiles[2].id))
            {
                event.addError('You do not have permission to delete this event');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `&&` not `||` would make more sense.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that!! Thank you @KeithC that solved it.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for Adrian's answer.

But when adding triggers to standard objects that are likely to be used by many apps in an org, it makes sense to not penalize those other apps with extra SOQL calls. So for this case something like the code below will only do the query when necessary:

```
trigger PreventEventDeletion on Event (before delete)
{
    Set<Id> allowedProfileIds = null;
    for (Event event : Trigger.old)           
    {           
        if (event.Type == 'Telemarketing Appointment')      
        {
            if (allowedProfileIds == null) {
                allowedProfileIds = new Map<Id, Profile>([
                        SELECT Id
                        FROM Profile
                        WHERE Name in ('System Administrator', 'Marketing Director', 'Telesales')
                        ]).keySet();
            }
            if (!allowedProfileIds.contains(UserInfo.getProfileId())) {
            {
                event.addError('You do not have permission to delete this event');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Saving a single query probably doesn't matter much, but you did inspire me to edit my own answer to save that same query, but we still have different approaches. Of course, if we were to be aggressive about optimization, lazy-loading a static flag in a class would be even more efficient.

Comment: This is excellent! I need to start following this approach next time I write my code..

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah you are probably right. But I see code quite often with fairly hefty queries done whether they need to be or not and that will impact org responsiveness. I'll admit getting to the governor limit breaking point is unlikely.

Comment: If you apply the approach that you only need to save queries once things are almost to the breaking point, they are going to break a lot faster. It is a good practice and an easy optimization to make.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic will be easier to understand if you use the `Set.contains` method:

```
Set<Id> profileIdWhitelist = new Set<Id>();
for (Profile whitelistedProfile : [SELECT Id FROM Profile]) // WHERE ...
    profileIdWhitelist.add(whitelistedProfile.Id);
if (!profileIdWhitelist.contains(UserInfo.getProfileId())
{
    for (Event event : trigger.old)
        // addError
}
```

It would probably be best to put this in a lazy loaded property somewhere:

```
public static Set<Id> eventDeletionProfiles
{
    get
    {
        if (eventDeletionProfiles == null)
        {
            eventDeletionProfiles = new Map<Id, Profile>([
                SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE...
            ]).keySet();
        }
        return eventDeletionProfiles
    }
    private set;
}
```

Comment: You should have added the id instead of the record. Regardless, you'd get better performance with the following: `Set<Id> allowedProfileIds = new Map<Id, Profile>([select id from profile...]).keySet();` which foregoes the loop entirely. Similarly, you should import the user's profile ID to a local variable, because it's more efficient: `Id userProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();`.

Comment: Good point. In some ways it is counter-intuitive that would be more efficient, since the code has to build up an additional data structure. It would be interesting to profile that.

Answer (score 4):

There's an even easier way to abort early. Simply query for profiles that match a certain name *and* also match the user's current profile. If the result is non-zero, that means the user is authorized to delete the events.

```
trigger PreventEventDeletion on Event (before delete) {
    Event validEvents = new Event[0];
    for(Event event: Trigger.old) {
        if(event.Type == 'Telemarketing Appointment') {
            validEvents.add(event);
        }
    }
    if(validEvents.isEmpty() || [SELECT COUNT() 
        FROM Profile 
        WHERE Name IN ('System Administrator', 'Marketing Director', 'Telesales') AND
              Id IN :UserInfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1]==1) {
        return;
    }
    for(Event event: validEvents) {
        event.addError('You do not have permission to delete this event');
    }
}
```

Your trigger wouldn't work correctly, because if the user is, for example, a system administrator, they won't be a marketing director or telesales, and therefore the error would occur. Imagine the results of the statement:

- User is System Administrator.
- Profile != System Administrator == FALSE
- Profile != Marketing Director == TRUE >> Result is true, so show error.